# QR algorithm for tridiagonal matrix

Tags: algorithm

I have an A matrix.
I used HouseHolder algorithm and i found a tridiagonal matrix. Now, i want to decompose it to Q matrix, R matrix. 
then, i'll use my results to calculate eigenvalues and eigenVectors of A matrix.
Can anyone help me resolve my problem?
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It belongs to the [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/finding-matrix-eigenvectors-using-qr-decomposition

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem can be solved via [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: My pleasure! Have fun with whatever you're doing!